# Как ограничить доступ ко всей админке? JwT Laravel Angular

Tags: angularjs, laravel, cms

Хочу написать CMS используя `Laravel`, админка на `angular` и `JWT` аутентификацию. Как ограничить доступ ко всей админке?

web.php:

```
Route::get('/admin',function(){
   return view('index');
});
Route::get('/api/v1/employees/{id?}', 'Employees@index');
Route::get('/api/v1/users/{id?}', 'Employees@users');
Route::post('/api/v1/employees', 'Employees@store');
Route::post('/api/v1/employees/{id}', 'Employees@update');
Route::delete('/api/v1/employees/{id}', 'Employees@destroy');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
    Route::get('authenticate/user', 'AuthenticateController@getAuthenticatedUser');
});
```

когда пользователь переходит на `/admin`, грузится ларавелский `index.blade.php`, в котором есть все js-скрипты и `ui-view`, который выводит форму логина. После успешной аутентификации пользователя перекидывает на другую страницу (уже самой админки, скрипты дублируются).

Такую кашу заварил(

Comment: А ты не пробовал что-нибудь готовое? Ng-admin например

Comment: я просто хочу улучшить свои навыки. С аутентификацией что то запутался(

Comment: @AndreySoloviev куда уж еще готовее?:D конструторы из либ собирать?

Answer (score 0):

Для ограничения доступа куда-либо в Laravel, юзай Middleware
https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/middleware